# button image change using predefined method

Tags: iphone, ios

In my app am using UIScrollView. I added buttons to UIScrollView.
For each button i assigned image using

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state;
```

and actions.

forState i used **UIControlStateNormal**  in **viewDidLoad**.

And when we click on button image has to change.
For this i used same method but forState value changed to   **UIControlStateSelected** in **ViewDidLoad**.

But button image is not changing.
any one can help or suggest

Comment: Do you want to keep the alternate image after button is tapped or should the image just switch for the short time of tapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this line of code I think this will be helpful for you.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
 {
    UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
    [myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0,3,70,32)];
    [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"barbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(compete) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 }
 -(void)compete
 {
    [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"barbutton1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You've to use like this

In ViewDidLoad Set images for normal and selected state

```
-(void)ViewDidLaod

[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"barbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"barbutton1.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

To perform selection image change can be done below code

```
 -(void)buttonclick

[myButton setSelected:YES];
```

or

```
[myButton setSelected:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_highlighed.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```